# What should a technical thesis' conclusion entail of?

Tags: thesis, writing, conclusion-section

I can't speak for other CS students but I personally don't have much imagination regarding what to write sometimes. I have nearly finished finalizing my thesis regarding a Rubik's Cube Solver I have developed.

I'm having trouble writing the overall conclusions of the paper. The chapter is titled "Conclusions and Future Work". I had no issues writing a plethora of ideas for the Future Work but am struggling to think of good things to write in the conclusions section...

Any recommendations would be brilliant. THANK YOU!

p.s. Supervisor is busy marking work, thus does not reply as fast as the stack-exchange. I have emailed him regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discuss your main conclusion(s) in a few sentences. Discuss the approach to the solution; the general structure of the technique. If you specialize a known technique, name the one you specialize (or generalize, perhaps). Discuss any comparisons with earlier work. You can point to various sections of the paper for details if you like.

Comment: There's the thing, I have 5 solutions for solving the Rubik's Cube. I've discussed the approaches and results for all of them in previous sections. I could compare with previous work as I did a literature review earlier on... I'll see what I can do with what you've currently described :)

Comment: Just a quick summary. For five solutions, maybe they fall into fewer classifications. But you don't need to say a lot. Think of it as if you were writing an abstract or describing your work to someone during a ride in an elevator.